# Uncaught ReferenceError: WindowsAzure is not defined

Tags: android, azure, cordova

I finished this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started.

The outcome is a simple app.

The problem is this app works for me in a browser but doesn't work on an emulator (android) or an actual device(android).

Im getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: WindowsAzure is not defined

What is the reason behind that?

Comment: You could refer to this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e570f07a-a23b-499d-9af9-3aaebd9780da/error-windowsazure-is-not-defined?forum=azuremobile), maybe will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue than you.

You can test my workarround :

1. to uninstall the android platform

> ```
> cordova platform rm android
> ```

2. to uninstall the plugin

> ```
> cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-azure-mobile-apps
> ```

3. to re-install the platform

> ```
> cordova platform add android
> ```

4. to install the plugin version 2.0.0 (the build fails with the
   version 2.0.1)

> ```
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-azure-mobile-apps@2.0.0
> ```

5. run the app on device

> ```
> cordova run android --device
> ```

See all the discussion on :
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e570f07a-a23b-499d-9af9-3aaebd9780da/error-windowsazure-is-not-defined?forum=azuremobile

I hope it will work for you too.